# more rows returned from query with pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP w/PDO using MySQL and the problem I am having is I execute a SQL statement and write out the results in HTML. Then another SQL statement executes and the problem is row's are being returned that should not be returned. I know this is true because when I execute this second query in PHPMyAdmin I get the results that I expect. The environment as follows (PHP 5.2.17, MySQL 5.30, Apache 2.2.25). Just to throw a monkey wrench into the situation it works like it should on my pc. Here is the SQL stmt if it helps:

```
$unusedContactsQuery = $dbc->prepare("select idContact, contactName 
from contactinfo
where iduser = :iduser
and contactAuthorized = 1
and idcontact not in (select a.idcontact from  contactinfo a                    
        inner join eventcontacts c on a.idContact = c.idContact
            inner join eventschedule b on c.idEventContact = b.idEventContact
                where b.idEventContact = :idEventContact
                and a.iduser = :iduser
                and contactAuthorized = 1)");
```

*Contact List:
Bella Lugosi
woody woodpecker
Bucky Winters
Bella Lugosi
woody woodpecker

Bella Lugosi and woody woodpecker are duplicate of the first two names at the top of that list. The first query returns the first two names (i did a rowCount() on that query and it displayed 2 and I did a rowCount() on the 2nd query and it displayed a 3, so the last three names were pulled back from the 2nd query) So does anybody have any idea why this is happening? (The 2nd query pulling back rows that should not be retrieved when the same query works correctly in PHPMyAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say the parameters are not the same in the two queries.  There's no reason for the same query to return a different number of rows.

Rather than doing a `NOT IN`, I'd suggest joining directly on to `contactinfo` with left joins and looking for null rows - it'll most likely be faster too.

It's hard to re-write the query without the data to test on but try

```
SELECT idContact, contactName 
FROM contactinfo ci
LEFT JOIN eventcontacts ec USING(idContact)
LEFT JOIN eventschedule es USING(idEventContact)

WHERE ci.iduser = :iduser 
AND ec.idEventContact = :idEventContact 
AND ci.contactAuthorized = 1 
AND es.idEventContact IS NULL
```